# will the Live Agent work with localhost?

Tags: liveagent

i have generated the code for Chat button and trying to install Tomcat web server in my machine to paste the code in one of the webpage. My question is, will the Live Agent work with localhost? Is that possible to whitelist the localhost in salesforce? i dont have a webserver with an internet IP.

Thanks,
Baskaran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to set up a local server to play with LiveAgent. Just paste the button code and deployment code in a file on your desktop and it should work just fine as long are you have not set up a list of white-listed domains.

Comment: i didnt understand "in a file on your desktop" and also deployment code. what kind of file a batch file or text file. how it works?

Comment: All you need is a html file (a web page) that hosts the code generated by Salesforce when you created the Chat button(s) and the page also needs to host the deployment code which is also generated by Salesforce. Obviously to test it out you will need a user online. By desktop, I meant to say, a file anywhere on your computer, it does not have to be on a server.

Comment: i little confused, but now i understand it better. Thanks, @PepeFloyd